# Getting Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence') error while inserting data using hibernate into Postgres

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I am new to Hibernate. I am using Postgres as my database. I have created a simple book class and trying to store data into database table named `book`

This is my Book class:

```
    package com.techno.domain;

public class Book {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String authur;
    private String year_published;
    private String genere;
    private int no_of_piece;

    /**
     * Default Constructor
     */
    public Book() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     * @param authur
     * @param year_published
     * @param genere
     * @param no_of_piece
     */
    public Book(String name, String authur, String year_published, String genere, int no_of_piece) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.authur = authur;
        this.year_published = year_published;
        this.genere = genere;
        this.no_of_piece = no_of_piece;
    }

    /**
     * @param id
     * @param name
     * @param authur
     * @param year_published
     * @param genere
     * @param no_of_piece
     */
    public Book(int id, String name, String authur, String year_published, String genere, int no_of_piece) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.authur = authur;
        this.year_published = year_published;
        this.genere = genere;
        this.no_of_piece = no_of_piece;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id
     *            the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     *            the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the authur
     */
    public String getAuthur() {
        return authur;
    }

    /**
     * @param authur
     *            the authur to set
     */
    public void setAuthur(String authur) {
        this.authur = authur;
    }

    /**
     * @return the year_published
     */
    public String getYear_published() {
        return year_published;
    }

    /**
     * @param year_published
     *            the year_published to set
     */
    public void setYear_published(String year_published) {
        this.year_published = year_published;
    }

    /**
     * @return the genere
     */
    public String getGenere() {
        return genere;
    }

    /**
     * @param genere
     *            the genere to set
     */
    public void setGenere(String genere) {
        this.genere = genere;
    }

    /**
     * @return the no_of_piece
     */
    public int getNo_of_piece() {
        return no_of_piece;
    }

    /**
     * @param no_of_piece
     *            the no_of_piece to set
     */
    public void setNo_of_piece(int no_of_piece) {
        this.no_of_piece = no_of_piece;
    }
}
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/library</property>
        <property name="connection.username">test</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property> -->
        <!-- Use XML-based mapping metadata -->
        <mapping resource="com/techno/domain/Book.hbm.xml"/>

        <!-- Use Annotation-based mapping metadata -->
        <!-- <mapping class="com.techno.entity.Book" /> -->


    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My Book.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.techno.domain.Book" table="book">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">book_id_seq</param>
            </generator>

        </id>
        <property name="authur" type="string" column="authur" />
        <property name="genere" type="string" column="genre" />
        <property name="name" type="string" column="name" />
        <property name="year_published" type="string" column="year_published" />
        <property name="no_of_piece" type="int" column="no_of_piece" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am not able to figure it out where I am doing this wrong. I am constantly getting this error.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure$1.getNextValue(SequenceStructure.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:417)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at com.techno.libraryOwner.LibraryOwner.main(LibraryOwner.java:20)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
  Position: 17
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2003)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:161)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<id name="id" type="int" column="id">
      <generator class="sequence">book_id_seq
           <param name="sequence">book_id_seq</param>
      </generator>
</id>
```